# Playing a monetized YouTube song inside of a Google Chrome Extension. Do I have any options?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have encountered a huge roadblock in the development of my Google Chrome extension. Any YouTube song which is monetized (e.g. has an advertisement) will not play.

This is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference_as2#Events

as well as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852490/some-videos-not-playing-through-youtube-api

Previously, I had been using YouTube's Flash API. This worked great until I attempted to deploy my extension. At that point I encountered huge security issues which locked down the app due to insufficient privileges. As such, I rewrote the player to use the iFrame API instead of the Flash API.

The iFrame API allowed me to deploy successfully without any Flash security concerns, but now I am unable to play any song with an advertisement in it.

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Edit:

My extension can be downloaded here: http://www.meomixes.com/

The source for the extension can be seen here: http://github.com/MeoMix/YouPod

As an example, this song works perfectly OK for me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXtPoNfOYSo

This song, however, throws an error upon playing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dfVAAWbLUY

Note that the second song has been monetized.

Comment: Do you have a demo? Is the issue specific to Chrome extensions?

Comment: I've edited in a working demo of the extension with songs that do/do not have the issue, pushed my current source to GitHub. I believe other people do not experience this issue because they use the AS3 API and not the iFrame API. AS2 is said to have a limitation according to the youtube documentation. I am assuming that limitation extends to iFrame, too. Wondering if there is a work around, or perhaps back to trying to figure out how to resolve security issues running flash in my extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I initialised the player and loaded the video:

[image: player = new YT.Player(getFrameID('MusicHolder'));player.loadVideoById('_dfVAAWbLUY')]

As you can see, the player refused to embed the video, because the player is too small. So, I changed the size of the player, and tried again:

[image: $('iframe').width(640).height(390);player.loadVideoById('_dfVAAWbLUY');]

The video started playing. I've tested the same code in an extension, and the problem also disappeared.

So, create the dummy frame as follows:

```
<iframe
    width="640"
    height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dummy?enablejsapi=1"
></iframe>
```

Some more debugging information:

- In the previous screenshots, `http://localhost:8000/` is the root directory of the chrome extension. I used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to create the server.
- I intercepted the messages between the frame and the page, and found that error code 150 was thrown. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events), this "is the same as 101", and "the 101 error code is broadcast when the video requested does not allow playback in the embedded players."

[image: player = new YT.Player(getFrameID('MusicHolder'));onmessage=console.log.bind(console);player.loadVideoById('_dfVAAWbLUY')]

Comment: GAH. Teach me your ways. I thought the issue might have been that. My idea was to pass parameters into YTPlayer, but then I learned that YTPlayer had default dimensions larger than 200x200. So, I moved on to other issues thinking it was not the size. I did not even consider it possible to view the background page... but you've shown how to do it. I'm frustrated and awed by your ability to debug this for me. Thank you. I obviously still have quite a lot to learn.